# Tabs not aligned properly on profile modal

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

It looks like a new visual look for careers rolled out and there is something strange happening with the tabs on the profile page.

[image: tabs are not aligned correctly]

It looks like the code to track the active tab is not working properly as well.

[image: active ALL the tabs]

Comment: I dont get a downvote... It was a bug report and now bug is fixed. Is it bad?

Answer (score 5):

**Darren** — Yes, we noticed the bug ourselves earlier today. Fixes have been pushed to production.